# Using Guzzle instead Curl

Tags: laravel, curl, guzzle

Im using Guzzle instead Curl, to make a post request, but is not working when i try to replace a working Curl example with a Guzzle. I alreadry tried other solutions but still giving me a wrong credentials, what it doesnt makes sense since it works using Curl and i also test the credentials using Postman

My working curl is:

```
 $params = array(
                'account'       => 'username',
                'licensekey'    => '2669asdas',
                'phoneNumber'   => preg_replace('/\D/', '', $recipient),
                'messageText'   => $message,
                'alfaSender'    => 'somehting'
            );


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array(
          $ch,
          array(
          CURLOPT_URL            => 'https://domain/API/send',
          CURLOPT_HEADER            => false,
          CURLOPT_POST           => true,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => http_build_query($params),
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        )
      );

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
```

My not workign Guzzle example:

```
$client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
$send_sms = $client->post('https://domainpt/API/send', [
    'debug' => true,

    'form_params' => [
        'account' => 'username',
        'licensekey' => 'passs',
        'phoneNumber' => '96163233',
        'messageText' => 'blbaaa',
        'alfaSender' => 'Felo',


    ]
]);
```

Error:

```
Client error: `POST https://domain/API/send` resulted in a `401 Wrong Credentials` response: {"Result":"NOT OK", "ErrorCode":2, "ErrorDesc":"Wrong Credentials"}
```

Comment: try something like this `$vars = array('state[]' => array('Assigned','New'), 'per_page' => $perPage, 'page' => $pageNumber);
$query = http_build_query($vars, null, '&');
$string = preg_replace('/%5B(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)%5D=/', '=', $query); // state[]=Assigned&state[]=New
$client = new Client([follow instruction to initialize your client ....]);
$response = $client->request('POST', $uri, ['query' => $string]);`

Comment: I think your request is working fine, it resulted in 401 because of the wrong credentials given. All you need is to catch that response and return to your user side.